# How to return element values as a result of a value check of one of those elements

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

```
<routes>
    <drivinginstruction>
        <start>SA5 9BZ, UK</start>
        <end>CF2 5RF, UK</end>
        <time>2 hours, 12 minutes</time>
        <total_distance>429.83</total_distance>
        <step>
            <id>1</id>
            <instruction>Start out going SOUTHWEST on Unamed Road.</instruction>
            <distance>0.1</distance>
        </step> 
        <step>
            <id>2</id>
            <instruction>Turn LEFT onto Unamed Road.</instruction>
            <distance>0.2</distance>
        </step> 
        <step>
            <id>3</id>
            <instruction>Take the SECOND exit.</instruction>
            <distance>0.1</distance>
        </step> 
    </drivinginstruction>
</routes>
```

I want to use xpath 2.0 to grab id and distance where distance is < 1.
This is how far I've got.

```
if (routes/drivinginstruction/step/distance[@value < 1.0]) then routes/drivinginstruction/step/(id|distance) else 0
```

This returns 0.
Can anyone help please.

Regards Paul.

Comment: Does `//routes//step[./distance<1]/(id|distance)` works for you? Note that `distance` has no `@value` attribute

Comment: Gives me the following error.  SaxonCE.XSLT20Processor 11:01:12.740 SEVERE: XPathException in invokeTransform: Required item type of first operand of '<' is numeric. Cannot convert string (zero-length-string) to a double

Comment: @Finchy70 So you want to return `id` & `distance` if `distance < 1` and return `0` otherwise, or just don't return anything otherwise? Can you post the expected output?

Comment: Just return id and distance if distance is < 1.  Don't return anything otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `@value` references attribute named 'value' which isn't exist in your XML. You want to use `.` to get the element's value instead. Anyways, you can achieve that without `if`, just XPath predicate :

```
routes/drivinginstruction/step[distance < 1.0]/(id|distance)
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/7c7bbdf4923eb70af3bf1ced3575c272)</kbd>**

or using the XPath 1.0 compatible version :

```
routes/drivinginstruction/step[distance < 1.0]/*[self::id|self::distance]
```

---

**UPDATE**

The problem with your full XML is, probably, that one of the `distance` element is empty which caused error when compared to a decimal number. Assuming that you don't want to return anything from `distance` element that doesn't contain valid number value, then you can add another predicate to check this before :

```
/routes/drivinginstruction/step[number(distance)][distance < 1.0]/(id|distance)
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/e386ae422268f53159732f8425b2c811)</kbd>**

Comment: Using PathEnq to run the xpath 2.0 instruction I get no results but I also get no errors.

Comment: There were some typos, can you try the updated XPath? It worked in the linked demo site

Comment: Ive included the full xml.

Comment: When I add the complete set of xml data it does not work for me.

Comment: @Finchy70 check the **UPDATE** section

Answer (score 0):

Using the advice given to me by har07 I made a slight change to his answer as it would not give me the results across my full xml in PathEnq.
Here is the final Xpath 2.0 query that worked.

```
/routes/drivinginstruction/step/distance[number(.)< 1]/../(id|distance)
```

Thanks to everyone who provided input.